# error in calculating the posterior in basic urn sampling problem

Tags: bayes-theorem, sampling

As I'm reading E.T. Jaynes' Probability Theory and while trying to do some calculations by myself (in this particular case, re-derive equation 6.15) I'm running into a problem where I just can't find my mistake:

We have an urn containing N balls in total of which R are red and the remaining N-R are white. N is known and we draw n balls at random of which r are red. Given the outcome of our draws we now try to estimate R using Bayes theorem:

$$ \underbrace{p(R | r, n, N)}_{\text{posterior}} = \underbrace{p(R | N)}_{\text{prior}} \frac{\overbrace{p(r | n, N, R)}^{\text{sampling distribution}}}{\underbrace{p(r | n,  N)}_{\text{marginalization}}} $$

Using a uniform prior and the hypergeometric distribution as the sampling distribution:

\begin{align*}
  \text{prior}                 &= \frac{1}{N+1} \\
  \text{sampling distribution} &= \frac{{{R}\choose{r}} {{N-R}\choose{n-r}}}{{{N}\choose{n}}} \\
  \text{marginalization}       &= \frac{\sum_{R=0}^N {{R}\choose{r}} {{N-R}\choose{n-r}}}{{{N}\choose{n}}} \stackrel{\text{vandermonde's idenity}}{=} \frac{{{N+1}\choose{n+1}}}{{{N}\choose{n}}}
\end{align*}

the ${N \choose n}$ cancel out and I get:
$$ p(R | r, n, N) = \frac{1}{N+1} \frac{{{R}\choose{r}} {{N-R}\choose{n-r}}}{{{N+1}\choose{n+1}}}$$

But this is not properly normalized. The prior $\frac{1}{N+1}$ should cancel out too somehow to arrive at the correct result of just $\frac{{{R}\choose{r}} {{N-R}\choose{n-r}}}{{{N+1}\choose{n+1}}}$.

I just don't see how. What am I missing/what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

And just after posting the question, a friend pointed out the error to me:
the marginalization should be:
$$\sum_{R=0}^N p(r,R|n,N) = \sum_{R=0}^N p(r|R,n,N) \underbrace{p(R|n,N)}_{=p(R|N)}$$